# How to use GAPI in Tampermonkey JS Script? I'm trying to use google sheets API for my tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So I'm trying to make a tampermonkey script, and I'm a beginner in JS, and I want to add the google API library to my code to make gapi work, since I want to write into spreadsheets from my JS tampermonkey script. How do I define gapi? I already added

```
// @require      https://apis.google.com/js/api.js
```

This is the function I'm trying to use

```
function getValues(spreadsheetId, range, callback) {
  // [START sheets_get_values]
  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: range
  }).then((response) => {
    var result = response.result;
    var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
    console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    callback(response);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
  });
  // [END sheets_get_values]
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions provided [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)?